# How to insert date from a coldfusion variable to a sql field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, coldfusion

Because of an unusual setup of code, instead of using cfquery with cfparam tags, I am instead building a sqlInsertCols list and a sqlInsertValues list and using those in an insert statement. Code something like this:

```
<cfscript>
   var sqlInsertCols = "";
   var sqlInsertValues = "";
   // some looping and other processing here to fill the lists
   ...
</cfscript>

<cfquery datasource="..." name="insert">
   INSERT INTO MyTable(#sqlInsertACols#)
   VALUES (#sqlInsertVals#)
</cfquery>
```

Firstly, are there any security issues with this, considering that both sql strings are populated within this code and not based on any user input?

And this has worked for several fields that I was inserting, but I just tried to add a date field and can't get the insert to work. The date is in the format "mm/dd/yyyy". Code to add date to sql lists:

```
sqlInsertCols = ListAppend(sqlInsertCols, "MyDateField");
sqlInsertValues = ListAppend(sqlInsertValues, myDateVar);
```

This runs with no errors but the value in the db is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

I've tried adding quotes around the date but can't seem to get it to insert properly. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try `sqlInsertValues = ListAppend(sqlInsertValues, CreateODBCDateTime(myDateVar));`.

Comment: @xpa1492 - that worked! Thank you! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Slightly more efficient than @xpa1492's recommendation is to create date variables in the first place instead of string variables which you then convert.

Comment: *not based on any user input* What exactly is the source? If this data comes from another table in your db, why not just use INSERT INTO/SELECT? Otherwise, the code may still be at risk of sql injection. Also, why not use the cfscript version of cfquery? Then you can use cfqueryparam and gain the performance benefits of bind variables.

Comment: @DanBracuk - we get the date as a string. It's scraped from a web page.

Comment: @Leigh - it's being scraped from a web page. How would the cfscript version of cfquery allow this functionality?

Comment: If it's being scraped from a web page you probably want to validate it first.  I would do something like this:  if (isDate() and something to check the format) myDateVar = parseDateTime(), or myDateVar = CreateDate().

Comment: @froadie - Then it is not really safe. The [cfscript version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html) allows you to build a parametrized sql string, dynamically, and use addParam to fill in the values. Side note, since you cannot use cfqueryparam on object names (table/column), be sure the column list consists of value *you* hard code in your app.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Sever uses single quotes around dates. Have you tried those?

Comment: I have tried, but CF seems to translate those to double quotes in the insert statement and then it causes an error.

Comment: @froadie: You'd need to use the `preserveSingleQuotes()` function.

Comment: *SQL Sever uses single quotes around dates* Not exactly. Quotes are required around string literals. In this case a date string. Depending on target column, that string *may* be implicitly converted to `date/time`, but it is still a string. @froadie - The reason the quotes are doubled is a security feature of CF. Queries that do not use cfqueryparam are at risk for sql injection, so CF automatically doubles quotes in an attempt to prevent that. `preserveSingleQuotes` reverses that behavior, but in doing so **exposes your db to the very thing CF tried to prevent**. So use it with caution.

Comment: Plus 1 to get Eric's reputation high enough to post comments.

Answer (score 1):

First let me say that I simply don't like this approach. It appears that you are trying to use cfquery as a generic wrapper - a way to "plug in" lists of variables. That makes your queries obscured by other code. Seeing as how queries are the most vulnerable vector, not to mention usually containing user input, it makes everything harder to troubleshoot. Moreover, cfquery is a *strength* of the CF language - one of the few languages that you can cut and paste from a DB IDE and simple change the variable inputs (adding cfqueryparam of course).

Finally, your query NEEDS cfqueryparam to protect from SQLi - so in answer to the last part of your question - yes this code is vulnerable. There is rarely if ever a case for not using cfqueryparam.

So... here's a solution (which again, I don't like or recommend :) that you can use as a starting point:

```
<cfscript>
   var sqlInsertCols = "";
   var sqlInsertValues = "";
   // some looping and other processing here to fill the lists
   ...
</cfscript>

<cfquery datasource="..." name="insert">
   INSERT INTO MyTable(#sqlInsertACols#)
   VALUES (
    <cfloop list="#sqlinsertValues#" index="colVal">
        <cfif isDate(colVal)>
            <Cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#colval#"/>
        <cfelse>
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value="#colval#"/>
        </cfif>
    <cfif colVal IS NOT listlast(sqlInsertValues)>
              ,
       </cfif>
    </cfloop>

   )
</cfquery>
```

This assumes that a field identified as a date is being inserted into a column in the DB of type "date". It also assumes that all the "other" non date fields are character fields. You might need to add checks for numbers or ints or whatever is in your data.

Additionally if you need to check the column name against the value you can use listgetat as follows:

```
<cfscript>
   var sqlInsertCols = "";
   var sqlInsertValues = "";
   // some looping and other processing here to fill the lists
   ...
</cfscript>

<cfquery datasource="..." name="insert">
   INSERT INTO MyTable(#sqlInsertACols#)
   VALUES (
    <cfloop from="1" to="#listlen(sqlinsertValues)#" index="x">
        <cfif listgetat(sqlInsertCols,x) IS 'dateadded'>
            <Cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#listgetat(sqlInsertValues,x)#"/>
        <cfelseif listgetat(sqlInsertCols,x) IS 'userid'>>
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#listgetat(sqlInsertValues,x)#"/>
        </cfif>

       <cfif x IS NOT listlen(sqlInsertValues)>
            ,
          </cfif>

    </cfloop>
   )
</cfquery>
```

Finally, for the completely *not recommended quick and dirty* solution you can try this:

```
<cfscript>
   var sqlInsertCols = "";
   var sqlInsertValues = "";
   // some looping and other processing here to fill the lists
   ...
</cfscript>

<cfquery datasource="..." name="insert">
   INSERT INTO MyTable(#sqlInsertACols#)
   VALUES (
    <cfloop list="#sqlinsertValues#" index="colVal">

        '#colval#'
            <cfif colVal IS NOT listlast(sqlInsertValues)>
                  ,
           </cfif>
    </cfloop>

   )
</cfquery>
```

This may work because of your RDBMS implicit conversion - which can convert down from character to date, int or numeric in many/most cases. of course you may just as easily get a syntax error.

One final note: the first and third samples above use some simple methods to insert commas in the list - comparing the value to the last value in the list and inserting if they don't match. So this assumes that any item coming *not last* in the list is not the same as the last item in the list. If that last item is duplicated elswhere in your query, then you will get a syntax error for a missing comma. Good luck!

ERRATA:
FYI - on that last snippet - the single quotes OUTSIDE the variable are not escaped by CFQUERY .. so when you use '#varName#' - the single quotes are preserved, but when they are inside the variable they are escaped - because CF naturally assumes (and best practice dictates) that you are handling the *contents* to be inserted in variable form, and not query language itself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Some of this is very useful. I'm going to be restructuring the way I do it somewhat (I'll have a sort of "lookup" struct for the column names so that I can pull it based on the html but it's still controlled). I'll likely be using cfqueryparams in a loop.